# Buddhism in context, differences through SE Asia?

Tags: east-asian-buddhism

What are some specific cultural aspects of different countries in SE Asia that are integrated into Buddhism, but that might not actually be consider purely Buddhism?

In other words, comparatively, why is Buddhism in Thailand different than Buddhism in Cambodia.  And what would the main differences be?

Comment: This is not a good question, from my point of view -- it encourages answers to point fingers and say, "this isn't Buddhism" and "that isn't Buddhism" and "you're not Buddhist" (or "You're not a *pure* Buddhist"), etc. I think it's probably [a "**Broad comparison**" question](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1572/254) -- one of the few types of question that people decided couldn't be answered satisfactorily and so which shouldn't be asked.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it fits the definition of a "Broad comparison" question [defined in the FAQ](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1572/254).

Comment: So how might I reword it to allow people to share about the differences?  Ask only about one specific country?

Comment: I'm not sure how to reword it. Part of the problem is that it's a "broad comparison", another part is asking "not actually be consider purely Buddhism". If someone wants to say that Buddhism is practiced in Thailand, for example, I don't want to say, "Oh *that* is not Buddhism: not *pure* Buddhism." Do you think there's such a thing as pure Buddhism without cultural aspects? And if you are somehow asking about non-Buddhism, is that even on-topic on this site?

Comment: If you quoted and asked for an explanation of one sentence, like [this one from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhism_in_Thailand), "Buddhism in Thailand has also become integrated with folk religion as well as Chinese religions from the large Thai Chinese population", then I suppose that would be on-topic ... no explicit rule against it, in the FAQs ... I couldn't predict whether there would be good answers to that, though.

Comment: @ChrisW I was merely attempting to learn about the nuances in Buddhism, some of which are cultural.  Not trying to make negative comparisons from a “which one is right or more pure” perspective, but how is Buddhism and it’s practices unique.

Comment: So maybe a question like, "What's *unique* about Buddhism in each of the various countries? For example what characterizes Buddhism in Thailand but no-where else?" That might remove the value-judgement: calling a characteristic "unique" rather than "impure". It's still very broad though; each country has a different history. If you did make separate questions about each country, that might be more focused. But wouldn't a good answer still be too long for this format, e.g. [Buddhism in Thailand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhism_in_Thailand) hardly scratches the surface.

Comment: Can you narrow the question any further? Say what kind of topic, what type of characteristic, you are interested in? Or say *why* you're asking, in case that helps to clarify what you're asking (i.e. what to include in an answer)? The question currently includes history, politics, customs, doctrines, famous teachers (traditions), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Burma is the only one in the world that still have buddhist ancient learning system (mukkhapāṭha). The strongest buddhism country is Burma. The tipitaka-strictest nikāya is Shwegyin Nikaya of Burma.

About a hundred year ago, in colonization war, thailand began to lost our tipitaka memorizing system. We need to get western's learning culture to protect our land from colonial possession. The central region of Siam reform memorizing learning system to academic learning system. Mun's students (Phun acaro, etc) were the last tipitaka memorizers of thailand.

Mun was the north-eastern region of thailand, that got reform order from the central region. And Lao was the north-eastern colony of thailand at that time. So Lao tipitaka memorizing learning system had began to lost since that time, too. **Kambodia, also.**

Nowadays, Lao and Kambodia monks equal to thai mahanikaya tradition. They are not forest tradition.

Thailand and srilanka have lost tipitaka learning system in colonization war.

Thailand began to lost our tipitaka learning system about 1855 and after that years ([Bowring Treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowring_Treaty)).

The king trying to protect thailand by changing every rules of us. They also changed learning system of monk, too. They cancle memorized learning system, then took a writing learning system instead. We also started to lose abhidhamma learning system  at this time, too.

**Writing learning system is for kamaguna 5. They save memorizing times to consume kamaguna 5.**

**Arahanta haven't writen. They keep tipitaka in their mind.**

Before that time we still having tipitakathara, such as mun bhuritutto (he not memorized enough to be bhikkhu-parisūpaṭṭhāpaka). But after the changing, we never have tipitakathara anymore. The elder tipitakathara died. Never have any newer to be instead of them.

So, thailand loose our tipitaka learning system so long time ago in colonization war.

Buddhadasa was a monk after we lost tipitaka learning system. He is tipitaka cutter.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very broad.

Buddhism came to SE Asia after Hinduism therefore I think a better question is how did Buddhism integrate into SE Asian cultures rather than how did SE Asian cultures integrate into Buddhism.

For example, in Thailand, although there are thousands of Buddhist monks, the Buddhist monks do not aggressively teach Buddhism to the common people therefore common people still have many traditional beliefs based in [animism, ancestor worship](https://www.pattayaunlimited.com/thailands-animist-practices-and-beliefs/) and Hinduism.

> *Before Hinduism and Buddhism were introduced into Thailand there was only one religious belief, that belief was that a spirit world
>   existed, not only did the spirits exist but they were mightily
>   powerful and controlling, this belief is called Animism and it
>   manifests itself in the form of spirit worship. It might not be
>   strictly correct to call Animism a religion, maybe it is better
>   categorized as a spiritual belief (spirit worship), but it is without
>   doubt the oldest form of worship known to mankind, ‘Spirit Worship’ in
>   one form or another was practiced long before all the popular world
>   religions.*
>
> *The majority religion in Thailand is Buddhism, 95 percent of the population are Buddhist but the percentage of Thais who have animist
>   beliefs is probably slightly higher. Animism is practiced on a daily
>   basis by most Thai people, although their religion is Buddhism they
>   actually devote more of their time to Animist beliefs than they do
>   practicing Buddhism.*

Buddhism is not the official or national [religion of Thailand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religion_in_Thailand).

For example, the [kings of Thailand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rama_(Kings_of_Thailand)) are considered to be the reincarnations of the Hindu god Vishnu and many [Thai national emblems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emblem_of_Thailand) are Hindu.

In Bangkok is the well-known [Erawan Shrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erawan_Shrine) of Brahma.

In my experience in Thailand, monks mostly teach the common person to be generous, to not be angry & to have metta (loving-kindness & tolerance). Monks generally do not even teach morality, let alone higher Buddhist teachings, unless these are requested by the people.

Of all SE Asian countries, in my experience, the most authentic Buddhism is found in Thailand, possibly because the Thai have always been a very independent people; they can act objectively.

Therefore, one major influence of Thailand on Buddhism is Thai teachers, most notably [Buddhadasa Bhikkhu](http://www.suanmokkh.org/buddhadasa) & also Ajahn Chah (in terms of doctrine) and Ajahn Mun (in terms of monastic asceticism), was returning to the original essence of Buddhism.

For example, the Supreme Buddhist Patriarch of Thailand once said the common interpretations of heaven & hell are cultural rather than Buddhist, below:

> *On this very subject, His Holiness
>   critically analyses that the very concept and belief of heaven and hell in Buddhism is a cultural
>   influence of indigenous culture and belief. He states: (I quote) ‘the subject of cosmology appeared in
>   Buddhism is clearly can be seen that it is not ‘Buddhist teaching’ at all but an ancient geography. The
>   concept and belief about it was included in Buddhist Canon merely because of strong influence of
>   popular belief of the time. Later Commentaries further explain about heaven and hell in a greater
>   detail distant itself from the original teaching of the Buddha. If Buddhism teaches such belief on
>   heaven and hell it would not be Buddhism at all but an ancient geography. Buddha wouldn’t be the
>   Buddha who delivered the Noble Truth and ‘timeless’ message for mankind.’ (p. 1) (end of the
>   quote) He then shows in his teaching that the concept of heaven and hell in Buddhism are in fact
>   symbolic, representing the quality of mind and spirituality instead. One can be in heaven and hell in
>   this very earth and life. No need to wait until one dies. [28 September 2008
>   By Ven. Phra Anil Dhammasakiyo](https://web.archive.org/web/20111203195803/http://www.sangharaja.org/Article/Sunday_Dhamma_Talk_28_Sep_2008_Somdet_Birthday.pdf)*